# React - homepage data is copied to other pages

Tags: reactjs, routes, auth0

I am using React with Auth0 authentication (code from Auth0 pages) and my problem is that the homepage content is copied to all other pages. I have a navigation bar inside my App class that I want copied across all pages (and it is copied) but any other content added to the App class gets copied as well (which I don't want). I haven't been able to find proper documentation concerning routing with props and authentication in such a way. Any help would be appreciated.

**Routes.js**

```
const auth = new Auth();

const handleAuthentication = (nextState, replace) => {
  if (/access_token|id_token|error/.test(nextState.location.hash)) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
}

export const makeMainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter history={history} component={App}>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" render={(props) => <App auth={auth} {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/home" render={(props) => <Home auth={auth} {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/profile" render={(props) => (
            !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
              <Redirect to="/home"/>
            ) : (
              <Profile auth={auth} {...props} />
            )
          )} />
          <Route path="/ping" render={(props) => (
            !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
              <Redirect to="/home"/>
            ) : (
              <Ping auth={auth} {...props} />
            )
          )} />
          <Route path="/callback" render={(props) => {
            handleAuthentication(props);
            return <Callback {...props} /> 
          }}/>        
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  goTo(route) {
    this.props.history.replace(`/${route}`)
  }

  login() {
    this.props.auth.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.props.auth.logout();
  }

  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;

    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <div className="container nav-wrapper">
                    <a href="" onClick={this.goTo.bind(this, '')} className="brand-logo"><i className="material-icons">done_all</i> Rate IT</a>
                    <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                        <li><a onClick={this.goTo.bind(this, 'home')}>Home</a></li>
                        {
                            !isAuthenticated() && (
                                <li><a onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Log In</a></li>
                            )
                        }
                        {
                            isAuthenticated() && (
                                <li><a onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Log Out</a></li>
                            )
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the `exact` attribute into your /home Route component, as follows:

`<Route exact path="/home" render={(props) => <Home auth={auth} {...props} />} />`

Here's the relevant entry in the React Router v4 documentation:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: That doesn't work but adding `exact` to `<Route path="/" ...` seems like a good step. The content from App.js suddenly isn't copied to all pages like I wanted. Which also means there is no navigation bar in other pages. Moving the `<nav>` bar to separate class and adding it to other pages however throws: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined_. So I'm stuck again.

Comment: In case the only thing your App component contains is the navbar, there shouldn't be need to wrap it in a Route component - try replacing your route with this:

`<App auth={auth} {...props} history={history}/>`

Should this not work, try simply `import` -ing your `history` from the file it's defined in.

Comment: Additionally, I do not think the `BrowserRouter` component accepts a `component` prop - removing that shouldn't do any harm, either.

Comment: `<App auth={auth} history={history}/>` without the `{...props}` did the magic! The props are not defined outside of Route component. Thank you.